# UNITY 2D change rotation make button larger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, landscape, portrait

UNITY 2D change rotation make button larger.
How to keep the size or reduce size by the right way when i change from portrait to landscape.

**The problem is that the default portrait mode is OK. When I change the device orientation, it makes the button bigger than normal. I'm asking how to change the size when switching from portrait to landscape mode**

Portrait
[Portrait 1440x2960](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra48h.png)

Landscape
[Landscape 2960x1440](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn6sy.png)

This is my CANVAS setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpQys.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your UI Canvas scaler needs to scale with the screen size if you want UI components to properly scale with different resolutions. You can use anchors to make sure the components are always at your prefered x and y position.

[image]

You can learn further here
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Comment: Yes, I did that. The problem is that the default portrait mode is OK. When I change the device orientation, it makes the button bigger than normal. I'm asking how to change the size when switching from portrait to landscape mode